# HM-10 BLE module automatic reconnect

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I have an HM-10 BLE (v549 firmware) module with a PIN set. I want my phone to connect to it automatically. Is this possible with BLE modules?

The first time it is discovered, I click on it and, after entering the PIN, they are connected (as indicated by the LED that stopped blinking). Then if I turn off either the module or my phone's bluetooth and I turn them on again, nothing happens. The phone does not connect to the module, even if I click on it. I have to unpair from my device and repeat the process for a connection to be established.

How can I setup the HM-10 so that my phone will automatically connect to it whenever it is within range?

Thank you.

Comment: please add some code. how you're connecting with device?

Comment: The HM-10 is setup at type 1 and slave mode.  I do not have any code on the side of my phone. I'm trying to achieve automatic reconnection without an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Bluetooth settings don't provide the option of making connection with auto connect feature. By default auto connect parameter is false. So what you can do is download the [nrf connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en) app. App provides a feature of `connect with autoConnecct`.

**Note:** AutoConnect have few limitations:

- Auto Connect will not work if you turned mobile bluetooth Off and then turn it On.
- Auto Connect will not work if you destroy the app.